# How to set up Maven-built Eclipse RCP projects with bndtools

Tags: maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, tycho, bndtools

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP (3.7) application and build it with Maven and Tycho. I'd like to use bndtools' ability to monitor version numbers (inspired by the EclipseCon Europe 2013 talk ["Never A Wrong (Semantic) Version again!"](http://www.eclipsecon.org/europe2013/never-wrong-semantic-version-again).

Unfortunately the tutorial doesn't get me very far as I cannot simply create new bndtool projects, but need to use the ones I have already (Eclipse Plug-in projects with Maven natures).

How can this be set up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look to the bndtools source code on [github](https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools) you will see that the plugin itself is made with bndtools. I think it is a good starting point for you by just looking how they do it.

Comment: Thanks. While looking at the repo, however, I've noticed that they don't build with Maven though...